# Where should I copy a PHP file from wp-includes to, in order to override it in my child theme?

Tags: php, child-theme, core-modifications

I've seen plenty of questions about changing stuff inside `wp-includes` and plenty of answers saying don't, under any circumstances.  However, I *need* to change something that's currently in there!  I'm happy to make a copy of it and change that, but I don't know where to put it.  Should I make a `wp-includes` folder inside my child theme (at the same level as `functions.php`), for example?  I've tried putting it alongside my `functions.php` but it doesn't get picked up there.

EDIT: Specifically, what I want to do is modify `class-wp-embed.php` to include an extra line in its public `shortcode` function.

Comment: Never modify WP Core!!!!

Comment: You will need to explain exatly what. What is it what you want to achieve. What do you want to change. What should the expected output look like. Please read your question through the eyes of someone that you want help from. Will you exactly know what is being asked? Did you check the filters

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the core file. They're classes which means they can be extended. It'll require a bit of leg work but all you need to do is load an instance of the class and then extend/add to it. That's the beauty of OOP.That's if there isn't a hook to modify things with already, which there probably will be.

Answer (score 0):

You should never modify WordPress Core. The people who recommend you do this are mistaken. The reason for this is that when you update WordPress you loose all of your changes. It also means assumptions plugins make about how Core work can be broken by your changes.

Instead, if you need to change Core behaviour, remove things, add things, or modify them, you should use actions and filters.

E.g. If I want to echo 'hello world' in the head, I could do this:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    echo 'hello world';
} );
```

While it's tempting to open up `class-wp-embed.php` to add a new oembed provider and modify the `$providers` array in the constructor.

Or you can read further down and spot the filter:

```
$this->providers = apply_filters( 'oembed_providers', $providers );
```

Then use it to add a provider using the filter instead in your plugin:

```
add_filter( 'oembed_providers', function ( $providers ) {
    $providers['#http://(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch.*#i'] = array( 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed', true  );
    return $providers;
} );
```

As a final note, anything that adds functionality that can modify content, such as custom post types, taxonomies, shortcodes, oembeds, should not be in your theme. They should be in a plugin. The reason for this is data portability. The moment the user switches themes, all their oembeds shortcodes and custom post types are no longer available, or stop working.

As a final note, oembeds don't require the use of a shortcode, simply copy pasting the url into the editor on its own line will convert it into a full embed

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I think this might be the way for me to go, although my filter doesn't seem to be being called...  I've got a very simple filter now: `add_filter('embed_handler_html', function ($url) { return "***$url"; });` just to try it out, and the URL is not being changed.  I've got the call to `add_filter` in my theme's `functions.php` file; I know you said don't do this, but the theme has already been modified for functionality so definitely won't be swapped for another one!

Comment: Actually, it is being called, although doesn't seem to be having the desired effect.  I thought that returning the modified URL would cause that to be used instead, but I'm not now convinced that this is what the filter is for.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the hook and what you're trying to do with it, can you provide some context? Also keep in mind oembeds can be cached

Comment: It's actually really simple what I want to do: if the URL supplied for embedding begins with a slash, I take it to be an absolute path and prefix the output of `get_site_url()`!  This is so that I don't have to change URLs when copying pages between different platforms (e.g. development and production) that have different domain names.

Comment: Ah, a production <-> development content issue! That's an interesting question in of itself. Maybe asking it as a separate question would be better. Use the above comment in your answer as an example of what you tried to do to remedy the problem, and point to this question as part of your research

Comment: Yeah that's one thing I hate about WordPress: its insistence on using full URLs where they're not required!  I'd still like to get to the bottom of this question though.

Comment: I think you have the answer, q: should you modify core to override things, a: no, use hooks and filters. Now you know what to do, you should ask how to do it. It's a new question, and requires a lot of detail that isn't relevant to the question asked here ( you can ask as many questions as you like! )